# Magento MSI; add custom attribute to Sources in M2

Tags: stock, msi

we want to use multiple sources using Magento Multistock MSI.

2 of our 5 stock locations are called 'virtual'. They have stock that is not readily avilable but can be sold.

OUr idea is to mark these 2 warehouse as 'virtual'. Orders based on items from these locations should inherit the 'virtual' attribute.

**question**: how can we add a new attribute to Magento Multistock MSI Sources and show it under Sources configuration as a two options element?

thanks, Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MSI track we are going to add Source Type ExtensionAttribute to the Source entity. So that you could use that attribute when released.

While we did not release that part - you can do it by yourself. Here is Magento documentation to use - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Comment: Glad to hear. Is this planned for a certain release? Will also check the link

Comment: @snh_nl here is a link you can track - https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/issues/2153

Comment: Will it be in a next release? I see many small updates